# RestTemplate gets java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in JDK11

Tags: java, openjdk-11

After moving to JDK11 RestTemplate gets java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder

Here is a usage:
this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate()

Comment: XML isn't part of the JDK anymore so yes you will get that if you use XML. Also is is an INFO message or does your application not work?

Comment: Right, so you should probably `--add-modules java.xml`

Comment: @M.Deinum the app doesn't work, and I get that error

Comment: As documented that after java8 XML has been removed, you need to explicitly add the dependencies to your application. I would strongly suggest to read the documentation **before** doing any kind of upgrade to prevent issues like this.

Comment: I have added the  dependency :
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

But the same error appears